# What is this invisible, performance eating cell in a recycling ListView?

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

So I've had performance issues in my Xamarin.Forms app (on Android) using a `ListView`. The reason is, because I'm using a very complex custom control in the ListView's `ItemTemplate`.

To improve performance, I implemented a lot of caching functionality in my custom control and set the ListView's `CachingStrategy` to `RecycleElement`.

Performance didn't went better. So I digged down trying to find out what's the reason about.

I finally noticed some really strange bug and isolated it in a new, empty app. Code is as follows:

### MainPage.xaml

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:c="clr-namespace:ListViewBug.Controls"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:ListViewBug.ViewModels"
             x:Class="ListViewBug.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <vm:MainViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Numbers}" CachingStrategy="RetainElement"
              HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
              HasUnevenRows="True">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <c:TestControl Foo="{Binding}" />
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ContentPage>
```

### TestControl.cs

```
public class TestControl : Grid
{
    static int id = 0;
    int myid;

    public static readonly BindableProperty FooProperty = BindableProperty.Create("Foo", typeof(string), typeof(TestControl), "", BindingMode.OneWay, null, (bindable, oldValue, newValue) =>
    {
        int sourceId = ((TestControl)bindable).myid;
        Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID {0}. Old value: '{1}', New value: '{2}'", sourceId, oldValue, newValue));
    });

    public string Foo
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(FooProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FooProperty, value); }
    }

    public TestControl()
    {
        this.myid = ++id;

        Label label = new Label
        {
            Margin = new Thickness(0, 15),
            FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Medium, typeof(Label)),
            Text = this.myid.ToString()
        };
        this.Children?.Add(label);
    }
}
```

### MainViewModel.cs

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public List<string> Numbers { get; set; } = new List<string>()
    {
        "one",
        "two",
        "three",
        "four",
        "five",
        "six",
        "seven",
        "eight",
        "nine",
        "ten",
        "eleven",
        "twelve",
        "thirteen",
        "fourteen",
        "fifteen",
        "sixteen",
        "seventeen",
        "eighteen",
        "nineteen",
        "twenty"
    };
}
```

Notice that `CachingStrategy` is `RetainElement`. Every `TestControl` gets a unique ascending ID which is displayed in the UI. Let's run the app!

## Without recycling

[image: Screenshot with recycling disabled]

```
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 1. Old value: '', New value: ''
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 1. Old value: '', New value: 'one'
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 2. Old value: '', New value: ''
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 2. Old value: '', New value: 'two'
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 3. Old value: '', New value: ''
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 3. Old value: '', New value: 'three'
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 4. Old value: '', New value: ''
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 4. Old value: '', New value: 'four'
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 5. Old value: '', New value: ''
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 5. Old value: '', New value: 'five'
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 6. Old value: '', New value: ''
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 6. Old value: '', New value: 'six'
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 7. Old value: '', New value: ''
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 7. Old value: '', New value: 'seven'
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 8. Old value: '', New value: ''
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 8. Old value: '', New value: 'eight'
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 9. Old value: '', New value: ''
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 9. Old value: '', New value: 'nine'
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 10. Old value: '', New value: ''
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 10. Old value: '', New value: 'ten'
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 11. Old value: '', New value: ''
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 11. Old value: '', New value: 'eleven'
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 12. Old value: '', New value: ''
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 12. Old value: '', New value: 'twelve'
```

Well, every Binding gets fired twice for some reason. This does not happen in my actual app, so I don't care that much about. I also compare oldValue and newValue and do nothing if they're the same so this behaviour wouldn't affect performance.

The interesting things happen when we set `CachingStrategy` to `RecycleElement`:

## With recycling

[image: Screenshot with recycling enabled]

```
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 1. Old value: '', New value: ''
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 1. Old value: '', New value: 'one'
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 2. Old value: '', New value: ''
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 2. Old value: '', New value: 'one'
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 3. Old value: '', New value: ''
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 3. Old value: '', New value: 'two'
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 1. Old value: 'one', New value: 'two'
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 4. Old value: '', New value: ''
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 4. Old value: '', New value: 'three'
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 1. Old value: 'two', New value: 'three'
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 5. Old value: '', New value: ''
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 5. Old value: '', New value: 'four'
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 1. Old value: 'three', New value: 'four'
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 6. Old value: '', New value: ''
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 6. Old value: '', New value: 'five'
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 1. Old value: 'four', New value: 'five'
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 7. Old value: '', New value: ''
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 7. Old value: '', New value: 'six'
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 1. Old value: 'five', New value: 'six'
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 8. Old value: '', New value: ''
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 8. Old value: '', New value: 'seven'
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 1. Old value: 'six', New value: 'seven'
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 9. Old value: '', New value: ''
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 9. Old value: '', New value: 'eight'
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 1. Old value: 'seven', New value: 'eight'
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 10. Old value: '', New value: ''
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 10. Old value: '', New value: 'nine'
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 1. Old value: 'eight', New value: 'nine'
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 11. Old value: '', New value: ''
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 11. Old value: '', New value: 'ten'
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 1. Old value: 'nine', New value: 'ten'
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 12. Old value: '', New value: ''
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 12. Old value: '', New value: 'eleven'
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 1. Old value: 'ten', New value: 'eleven'
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 13. Old value: '', New value: ''
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 13. Old value: '', New value: 'twelve'
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 1. Old value: 'eleven', New value: 'twelve'
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 1. Old value: 'twelve', New value: 'one'
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 1. Old value: 'one', New value: 'two'
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 1. Old value: 'two', New value: 'three'
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 1. Old value: 'three', New value: 'four'
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 1. Old value: 'four', New value: 'five'
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 1. Old value: 'five', New value: 'six'
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 1. Old value: 'six', New value: 'seven'
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 1. Old value: 'seven', New value: 'eight'
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 1. Old value: 'eight', New value: 'nine'
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 1. Old value: 'nine', New value: 'ten'
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 1. Old value: 'ten', New value: 'eleven'
[0:] Refreshed Binding on TestControl with ID 1. Old value: 'eleven', New value: 'twelve'
```

Oops. Cell 1 is invisible, but it gets its Binding updated a lot. I didn't even touch the screen once, so no scrolling was involved.

When I tap the screen and scroll down about one or two pixels, the Binding of ID 1 gets refreshed about another 15 times.

Please refer to this video of me scrolling the `ListView`:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EuWTGclz7uc

This is an absolute performance killer in my real app, where `TestControl` is a really complex control.

Interestingly, in my real app it is ID 2 instead of ID 1 that's bugged. I assumed that it is always the second cell, so I ended up with returning instantly if the ID is 2. This made the ListView performance nice and smooth.

Now that I've been able to reproduce this problem with an ID other than 2, I'm scared about my own solution.

Thus my questions are: **What is this invisible cell, why is it getting so much Binding updates and how can I bypass the performance problems?**

I tested with Xamarin.Forms versions 2.3.4.247, 2.3.4.270 and 2.4.0.269-pre2 on

- a Samsung Galaxy S5 mini (Android 6.0)
- a Samsung Galaxy Tab S2 (Android 7.0)

I didn't test on an iOS device.

Comment: Did you try to remove the surrounding tags "ViewCell"?

Comment: @hugorgor Sorry, that won't work. Getting a `System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.` As far as I know, `ListView` can only display items that derive from `ViewCell`.

Comment: Can you post video/screenshot of what do you see after scrolling? does 1 show up on the screen or not?

Comment: 1 never shows up on screen. After scrolling, the list continues with 11, 12, 13, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ...
I'll add a screenshot showing.

Comment: Have you tried setting HasUnevenRows to false and giving the rows a constant height? I could imagine the rows having to do the binding to calculate the row's height.

Comment: Just edited my question and added the video.  
@Spongebrot Just tried with HasUnevenRows="False", added a HeightRequest to TestControl and Height to ViewCell ... no success either. 
Is any of you guys able to reproduce the bug? Boiled it down to the code included in my question.

Comment: I meant setting the RowHeight Property of the ListView Control

Answer (score 3):

Setting `CachingStrategy` to `RecycleElement` is messing your list view because you are using a value in `TextBock` that isn't retrieved from BindingContext. (`int myid;`).

Let's look at Xamarin documentation [RecycleElement](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/performance/#RecycleElement)

> However, it is generally the preferred choice, and **should be used in
>   the following circumstances**:
>
> 1. When each cell has a small to moderate number of bindings.
> 2. **When each cell's BindingContext defines all of the cell data.**
> 3. When each cell is largely similar, with the cell template unchanging.

During virtualization the cell will have its binding context updated, and so if an app uses this mode it must ensure that binding context updates are handled appropriately. All data about the cell must come from the binding context or consistency errors may occur.

You should consider using `RecycleElement` mode when each cell's BindingContext defines **all of the cell data**.  Your `int myid` is cell data but isn't defined by Binding Context.

**Why?**

I can give a guess, that in `RecycleElement` mode when scrolling: controls are not being changed, changes are only made to their bindings. I think it is done to reduce time for rendering controls. ( Also to reduce memory usage for large amount of items )

So Text-Block with `myId` **1** can serve as container for **"Two"** value. ( This is what virtualization means. )

**Answer:** Changing your `myId` logic, to retrieve it from `BindingContext` will do the trick.

Comment: I've added `myId` for debugging purposes because I was noticing that something was wrong and performance was bad. I just wanted to give each of my cells a unique ID.
I'll look into this.

Comment: Ok, let me know. Just keep in mind that BindingContext must define all of the cell data.

Comment: @Physikbuddha any luck with resolving issue?